# Перенос строк таблицы в новый столбец при достижении числа 6

Tags: php, html

Как сделать, чтобы при достижении числа строк таблицы = 6, он переходил на новый столбец. Т.е:

```
| 1 | 7 | 13 |
| 2 | 8 | 14 |
| 3 | 9 | 15 |
| 4 | 10| 16 |
| 5 | 11| 17 |
| 6 | 12| 18 |
```

Подумал сперва эту таблицу поместить в другую таблицу, где число строк = 6, но т.к у меня она через PHP строится,

```
    <table cellspacing='10'>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
printf("
        <tr>
            <td>%s,%s</td>
        </tr>", $row['title'], $row['link']);
}
?>
</table>
```

Запутался. А может и другим ходом надо делать. В этих делах я новичок. Посоветуйте мне как реализовать это. Либо алгоритм, либо кусок кода. Заранее спасибо

**UPDATE**

Хочу как в Metro, в Windows, плитки сделать. Горизонтальный скроллинг

Comment: А сколько записей возвращается? LIMIT в запросе к БД используется? Если записей мало, то в PHP можно сохранить результаты в массив и его обрабатывать как надо.

Если записей много, то может быть стоит выводить элементы в массив, описанный в скрипте на стороне клиента? А затем уже полученный массив выводить в саму html-ку. Будет медленнее, зато будет не так нагружать сервер.

И раз написали про другую таблицу, то почему бы не выводить кучу таблиц, расположенных одна за другой. Размер таблицы 1 столбец, 6 строк.

А может просто повернуть текст? Что-то типа -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); ?

Comment: Да, я могу перенести в другую таблицу. Но как узнать что там число записей уже достигло 6? @ВОРОН

Comment: Возможно, если таблица не принципиальна, то лучше использовать <div style="float:left"></div>, например. В таком случае, можно без проблем контролировать количество элементов в столбце и будет более адаптивно

Comment: Тогда мне ставить 6 div'ов. Это понял. А как перенос сделать??? Мне вручную не нужно. Нужно автоматизировать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сильно палками не бить.

```
    <?php
    $host="localhost";
    $user="user";
    $pass="";
    $bd_name="test_db_2";

    $link = mysql_connect("{$host}", "{$user}", "{$password}"); //соединение с MySQL
    mysql_select_db("{$bd_name}"); //выбор БД
    $show = mysql_query("SELECT title, content FROM win8menu"); //выборка из таблицы win8menu
    mysql_close($link); //разрываем соединение с MySQL
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <?php

        //записываем все значения из БД в массив
                $ind = 0; //индекс массива, в который записываем значения
                while($result = mysql_fetch_array($show)){
                    $mas[$ind] = $result['title'];
                    $ind++;
                    $mas[$ind] = $result['content'];
                    $ind++;
                }
                //определяем кол-во столбцов: узнаём кол-во элементов в массиве,
                //делим на 12 (т.к. в одну ячейку мы будем вставлять по 2 значения)
                //и округляем в большую сторону
                $numOfCols = ceil(count($mas)/12);
                //выводим дивы таблицей по 6 строк в столбце
                $ind = 0; //обнуляем индекс
                for($col = 0; $col < $numOfCols; $col++){ //цикл отвечающий за кол-во столбцов
                    echo '<div class="col">';
                    for($row = 0; $row < 6; $row++){ //цикл отвечающий за кол-во строк
                        if(!empty($mas[$ind])){ //проверка на наличие значений в массиве
                            echo "<div><h4>{$mas[$ind]}</h4>";
                            $ind++;
                            echo "<br/>{$mas[$ind]}</div>";
                            $ind++;
                        }
                    }
                    echo '</div>';
                }               
            ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

И стиль:

```
.col{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.col div{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

Со скроллингом уж как-нибудь сами...

Answer (score 1):

```
   <table cellspacing='10'>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$i++;
printf("

        <tr>
            <td>%s,%s</td>
        </tr>", $row['title'], $row['link']);

        if(($i % 6)==0) echo "  </tr>
  <tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

не помню html (таблицы ),но логику я надеюсь ты понял...